# Selenium webdriver selecting from a dropdown

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, remotewebdriver

I have been on this for a long time over 2 months. It is selecting from a drop-down box with Selenium. Everytime I try running the script it gives reports that it cannot find the element, what could be the problem.
THis is my code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(UserGroupsConstants.UserGroupType)).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(UserGroupsConstants.UserGroupTypeSearch)).SendKeys("User Role");
```

This is the second code I tried but didn't work as well

```
SelectElement se = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(UserGroupsConstants.UserGroupType))); 
se.SelectByText("User Role");
```

This is the image of the dropdown
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe it it seen as a value. Try installing firebug and see if "User Role" is seen a value or as a text. Or you could try : select se = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("yourIdHere"))); se.selectByVisibleText("User Role"); and make sure you imported the "select" library. And just one more thing. If it is indee a value you just change to selectByValue("User Role")

Answer (score 1):

In the view page source check whether dropdown field defined in a select tag or as a button tag. If the dropdown defined in a `<select>` tag below script should work:

```
final Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath-expression of dropdown selection")));
            droplist.selectByValue("User Role");
```

If the dropdown is defined `<button>` tag as a advanced selection, below code can help you.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("dropdown button xpath-expression")).click();
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath-expression of userrole"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(ele).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: This clearly is not a standard select tag. You can only use `Select ` class for the `<select>` tags. Second approach is more likely to work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is thus. Thanks for the contributors. After combining the information and a bit of personal research, I found a workaround for it. The very first thing is to find the dropdown and click it

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("Css Path of element")).Click();
```

Secondly, this it has a text field, the text to be selected should be searched using this line of code.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("Css Path of element")).SendKeys("User Role");
```

When it displays the list after the first click, manually find the xpath of value you'll want to select.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("Css path of the element to be selected")).Click();
```

That's all. I hope it helps.